# Add " | " in string if where string value is not null or empty

Tags: c#, linq

I want to add " | " in 3 string if string is not null or empty
Ex.

```
-> UserName | Phone | Email
```

in case UserName is null then  `Phone | Email`
in case UserName and Email both are null string contain only `PhoneNumber`.

some thing like this

```
var userName =string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir.UserName)?"": dir.UserName+ " | ";
var userEmail = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir.UserEmail) ? "" : dir.UserEmail+ " | " ;
var userphone = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir.UserPhoneNumber) ? "" :  dir.UserPhoneNumber;
var disply = userName + userEmail  + userphone;
```

Can it done by linq with less code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] all = {dir.UserName, dir.UserPhoneNumber, dir.UserEmail};
string result = string.Join(" | ", all.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)));
```

Comment: Thanks brother its works fine. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be following:
After you store the three Strings in an array:
1. Check if UserName is the only String not null
  - If it is then just print it, else proceed to 2.

2. Append | and Phone (Phone can't be null since 1. checks for it)
3. If there is a element at array index 2 append a | and the Email.
4. Done!

Side note: This will take more lines to code but it would be way more readable and simple code.